# Using matltlib displays a new window named Figure 1 (not responding)

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

```
from pymavlink import mavutil
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')

# Connect to Mission Planner

master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('udpin:localhost:14550')

# Create empty lists to store data

timestamps = \[\]
latitudes = \[\]
longitudes = \[\]

# Set up the plot

plt.figure()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(\[\], \[\], 'b-')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
plt.grid()
plt.draw() # draw the plot

# Function to update plot

def update_plot(timestamps, latitudes):
line.set_xdata(timestamps)
line.set_ydata(latitudes)
ax.relim()
ax.autoscale_view()
fig.canvas.flush_events()
fig.canvas.blit() # or draw()
fig.canvas.start_event_loop(0.001) #1 ms seems enough

# Main loop

while True:

    # Wait for a message
    msg = master.recv_match()
    if msg is not None:
    
        # Check for GPS message
        if msg.get_type() == 'GLOBAL_POSITION_INT':
    
            # Extract latitude and longitude
            lat = msg.lat / 1e7
            lon = msg.lon / 1e7
            timestamps.append(msg.time_boot_ms)
            latitudes.append(lat)
            
            # Update plot
            update_plot(timestamps, latitudes)

print(f"GPS Position: Latt={lat:.6f}, Lonn={lon:.6f}")
```

That is my code, I updated matplotlib and i changed the backend but it is always not responding. please help me resolve this problem . It's frustrating when even after updating matplotlib and changing the backend, my plot remains unresponsive.

Comment: `plt.figure()` creates a new, empty figure.  `plt.subplots()` creates a second figure, default filled with one empty subplot.  As you're not using the first figure, it's better not to create it.  If that isn't your only problem, please describe that problem carefully. Note that your post should also be understandable without the title.